# Netbeans Not showing Data

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I am having issues viewing the data from my mysql database via netbeans.

The problem is it returns the data but not ALL of it.

I ran the same queries via the mysql command line client and it produces ALL the data

Don't know what to do again, tried refreshing and refreshing so many times yet same result.(Even restarted). Any ideas or is it my laptop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what tool/plugin are you using? Version? What is the SQL command you are using?

Comment: This is NetBeans. No plugin needed.  :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the page size (at the top of the results view) to a larger value?

Comment: Mysql 5.6, netbeans 8.0 if it helps. Connection via Jdbc

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it official, the answer was to increase the page size (at the top of the results view in NetBeans) to a larger value.